# Unable to parse integer from Volley response

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to get the count of the documents in remote mongodb database. For that I am using custom query url. The url only returns an integer instead of a JSON packet. I am using Volley in android to make this query. The following code gives Error: `E/Error﹕ com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value 2 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject`

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            Log.d("onResponse", jsonObject.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e("Error",volleyError.toString() );
        }
    });
```

The request made using the url in a browser gives the following result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a JSON Request Use String request so it will return the response as a 2.

Answer (score -1):

so simple you can get this using

```
int value = yourjsonobject.getInt("key");
```

If it helps please let me know